# Keras Custom Function is extremely slow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, custom-function

I have written a custom loss function but it is extremely slow. It has taken hours in just model compilation. What could be the reason behind it ? Any way to optimize this code so that it could become faster?

The most of the Processing time it takes after printing '2 done'.

```python
def Loss(y_true, y_pred)  
.
some code
.
w = np.random.random( 5, 10, 8, 8, 3))
# tile to 5D
y_true = np.tile(y_true, (5, 1, 1, 1, 1))
y_pred = np.tile(y_pred, (5, 1, 1, 1, 1))

print('1 done')

x = np.sum(y_pred*w, axis=(3, 4), keepdims=True)
y = np.sum(y_true*w, axis=(3, 4), keepdims=True)

print('2 done')


x2 = np.sum((w* y_pred)**2, axis=(3, 4), keepdims=True) - x**2
y2 = np.sum((w* y_true)** 2, axis=(3, 4), keepdims=True) - y**2

print('2.5 done')

xy = np.sum(w * y_pred * y_true, axis=(3, 4), keepdims=True) - x * y
.
some code
.
return Loss
```

'

Loss Function : 

`def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    return Loss(y_true, y_pred)`

Comment: Including `print` functions in such kind of functions is an extremely bad idea...

Comment: I don't have debugging tools in Ipython Notebook. So, I had to check where it is going wrong. What could be alternate?

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` functions in `keras` loss function? You need to use either `keras.backend` or your backend ones.

Comment: I did try with Keras functions as well but they couldn't make any difference.